# Problem to upload a pdf to Google Cloud storage with Node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, google-cloud-storage, pdf-generation, pdfkit

I'm using PDFkit to upload a pdf but when i go to stream the pdf i received an error

This is the code of the uploadService:

```
     import { format } from 'util';
     import stream from 'stream';
     import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';
    
     const storage = new Storage();

     const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME);

    export const uploadStreamToGcs = async (data) => {
  const dataStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  
  dataStream.push(Buffer.from(data.toString(), 'base64'));
  dataStream.push(null);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    const blob = bucket.file('test_pdf_folder/testPDF.pdf');

    const blobStream = dataStream.pipe(
      blob.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
          'Content-disposition': `attachment; filename=test.pdf`,
        },
        resumable: false,
        public: true,
      }),
    );

    blobStream
      .on('finish', () => {
        const publicUrl = format(
          `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`,
        );
        resolve(publicUrl);
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

And this is the code of the controller :

```
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit';
import { uploadStreamToGcs } from '../services/upload/upload.service';
import { ApplicationError } from '../errors/Application.error';

export default {
getPdfLocation: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const doc = new PDFDocument();
      doc.fontSize(12);
      doc.text('TEST CREZIONE PDF', 10, 30, {
        align: 'center',
        width: 200,
      });
      doc.end();
      const streamToGCloud = await uploadStreamToGcs(doc);
      
      res.send({
        status: 'success',
        data: { streamToGCloud },
      });

 } catch (error) {
      throw new ApplicationError(error.statusCode, error.message);
    }
  },

};
```

When I go on the route I created to create the pdf, the folder with the pdf inside is created but the pdf cannot be opened as I receive an error.
PLEASE HELP ME TO RESOLVE THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: when I try to open the pdf on the bucket it gives an error: "Error
Failed to load PDF document."

Comment: Was it resolved somehow? Getting same issue...